# Is combination charts (area and bar charts) together possible using Morris?

Tags: jquery, morris.js

I have created an area chart using Morris. Now I need to add a bar graph with a different set of data and combine it in the same graph.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible with the latest Morris version: 0.5.1
You can only create individual graphs. You can't combine them.